# Pascal ObjectListView

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, objectlistview

I have been working with a wxpython control called `objectlistview` which makes it very easy to list objects directly in the listview. Is there a control similar to `objectlistview` in object pascal (lazarus in my case)?
I know how to attach an object to list, but its not the same, since the list/grid controls don't work directly with the objects.

Comment: Look at `TTIGrid` from `RTTICtrls` package and it's example `lazarus/components/rtticontrols/examples/exampleprojectgrid1.lpi` (Lazarus only)

Comment: This is off topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and we also have no idea what compiler you are using since you named two different ones

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I edited the question, hopefully it's on topic now

Comment: No, it's just as off topic. If you want a list view, use a list view.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I want a different kind of list view, but I got your point.

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto, I guess it's time to learn about rtti...

Comment: It's good to learn RTTI but for using [RTTI controls](http://wiki.freepascal.org/RTTI_controls) it is not necessary. Just look at example, it is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

In a form just drop a `TTIPropertyGrid` from the package RTTI controls.

[image]

Then in the code you can assign what the grid has to display, for example the current form itself:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TIPropertyGrid1.TIObject := self;
end;
```